# WiFi disconnect

Tags: wifi

Where I work we have several WiFi's with different frequency. I often get disconnected and have to reconnect by hand. When that happened again, I checked

```
journalctl
```

and got the following output:

```
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 00:24:a8:98:08:40
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo NetworkManager[292]: <info>  [1478276002.0335] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> completed
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: wlo1: associated
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from 00:24:a8:98:08:40 (capab=0x801 status=0 aid=6)
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:24:a8:98:08:40 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: Associated with 00:24:a8:98:08:40
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: wlo1: associate with 00:24:a8:98:08:40 (try 1/3)
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: wlo1: authenticated
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 00:24:a8:98:08:40 (SSID='BAR' freq=5180 MHz)
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: wlo1: send auth to 00:24:a8:98:08:40 (try 1/3)
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo NetworkManager[292]: <info>  [1478276002.0224] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo kernel: wlo1: authenticate with 00:24:a8:98:08:40
Nov 04 17:13:22 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:a8:98:08:40 (SSID='BAR' freq=5180 MHz)
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo NetworkManager[292]: <info>  [1478276001.9020] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo dhclient[10311]: receive_packet failed on wlo1: Network is down
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo NetworkManager[292]: <info>  [1478276001.7420] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: SME: Deauth request to the driver failed
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:24:a8:a7:90:50 status_code=17
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo NetworkManager[292]: <info>  [1478276001.7021] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: wlo1: 00:24:a8:a7:90:50 denied association (code=17)
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from 00:24:a8:a7:90:50 (capab=0x421 status=17 aid=0)
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: wlo1: associate with 00:24:a8:a7:90:50 (try 1/3)
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: wlo1: authenticated
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 00:24:a8:a7:90:50 (SSID='BAR' freq=2412 MHz)
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo NetworkManager[292]: <info>  [1478276001.6877] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: wlo1: send auth to 00:24:a8:a7:90:50 (try 1/3)
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: wlo1: authenticate with 00:24:a8:a7:90:50
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo kernel: wlo1: disconnect from AP 00:24:a8:98:08:40 for new auth to 00:24:a8:a7:90:50
Nov 04 17:13:21 foo wpa_supplicant[347]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:24:a8:a7:90:50 (SSID='BAR' freq=2412 MHz)
```

What I think could be interesting, is that the frequency changes. Could that be a problem? How can it be fixed?

I use `nmcli` to connect to Wifi's. I can connect to a Wifi given its SSID. Can I connect to a Wifi on a specific channel, such that when I reconnect I will not only be reconnected to the Wifi with the same SSID but also with the same frequency?

Edit: I realize that there *might* be a correlation by a changing number of people that use the same Wifi and me getting disconnected. In other words, I think that when people come with their laptops, my chances increase of getting disconnected. If people don't move, my connection is relatively stable. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Probably wrong wpa keys-passprase
check the correct of password.

Comment: @elbarna I can connect to the Wi-Fi just fine, it's just that I regularly get disconnected.

Comment: If the connection work(this mean ping to internet work,surfing work) but disconnect can be a radio problem,try to change channel and use the same channel on wpa and access point

Comment: @elbarna How can I control what channel I'm connected to? See also my updated question (at the end).

Comment: A lot of apps can show channel,the best is wifi-radar

Comment: @elbarna `nmcli` shows the channel as well. The question is, how can I connect to the same channel when I get disconnected (since I believe this is the problem in the first place, but to be honest, I don't know...)

Comment: I installed wifi-radar nonetheless and will give it a try.